# job scheduling in windows pc

Tags: virtualbox, job-scheduling, lsf

When I submitting to job I am using the following format

My questions are follows

1) Can I use my personal pc to execetute simulations. Like using `VirtualBox` and using one of the linux distribution ?

2) Is it possible to execute .out in the windows machine?

Sorry for my poor questions I am not expert on Linux systems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However now I don't have access to execute my job files on the LSF
>   server.

You should talk with your cluster administrator about this. Transferring data from laptop to cluster is a common task. I'm sure that they have best practices.

> 1) Can I use my personal pc to execetute simulations. Like using
>   VirtualBox and using one of the linux distribution ?

Impossible to say with the limited information in the question.  e.g., if your simulation software is licensed, then your laptop may not be eligible to use it.

> 2) Is it possible to execute .out in the windows machine?

Again, with the limited information in the question, its impossible to say.  But in general Linux binaries cannot be directly run on Windows.

Comment: the simulation software is not licensed. the question is what would be the linux code to execute the simulation ? just removing `bsub -q “RHEL7”` is enough? or there is something needs to be done?

Comment: Your machine would also have to join the cluster. i.e., be added to the lsf.cluster file. Usually cluster admin's restrict which machines can join, since a misconfigured machine can cause jobs to fail.

Comment: What is `execution_file.out`?  An executable binary or script or data file?  `bsub` is an LSF command. If you want to run your job on your laptop, I assume that you won't use LSF to launch the job.  Also, can you provide the output of `bqueues -l RHEL7`?